# adding mysql field to if statment

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone know why the below code isn't working

```
if($out['out'] = '$user')
```

I'm not sure how to do an `if` statment on a mysql field.

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate *not working*. What's the input, what do you expect to happen, what does actually happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace '**=**' with '**==**' and remove single quotation mark around **$user**:

`if($out['out'] == $user)`

Answer (score 2):

because you can not use variabls value in single quatation string, then use ==